# Hey so I’m spray painting my car

Tags: paint, paint-clearcoat

My car is a metallic paint and after priming, and painting it has caused a cut off line on my bonnet, how Can I get rid of it ? And also on my bumper it looks very off, I have attached photos as I am confused, I have not used lacquer yet as I’m unsure whether that will help: and might make it worse ?
[image][image]
It just seems off and I think lacquer will make it shine but it will still look uneven
What Can I do ?

Comment: To me this looks like the paint has not dried or adhered properly. I'd say it needs a respray.

Comment: Or a change in humidity, still respray ...

Comment: over a metallic paint you want a coat of clear lacquer.

Comment: Did you rub the clear coat back around where you were painting?

Comment: The paint dried for 24 hours now @weakmech if I add the coat of clear lacquer will that mean it will then come up again ? And peter do you mean spray a clear coat and then rub ?